# Custom jinja variable in apache superset

Tags: jinja2, apache-superset

I created the custom variable {{year_var}} in SQL lab and assigned a value in the parameter menù: {"year_var":2014}. After checking that the query is running I created a virtual dataset, a chart and a dashboard.
My question is: How can I assign a value to {{year_var}} from the filter menù in the dashboard?